# Ruby on rails count and group

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, group-by

Need to build a "Top 10" query that works with SQLite and Postgres.

Client model
Client `has_many :merchandises, :through => :orders, :source => :items`

I want to group merchandises ordered by product_id, get the count for each and sort by most product ordered top and limit to 10.

```
Client.last.merchandises.group(:product_id).count(:quantity)
SELECT COUNT("items"."quantity") AS count_quantity, product_id AS product_id FROM "items" INNER JOIN "orders" ON "items"."order_id" = "orders"."id" WHERE "orders"."client_id" = 2 GROUP BY product_id
=> {1=>91, 2=>1, 12=>1, 32=>1, 33=>1, 34=>1, 37=>1, 75=>1, 84=>1, 85=>1}
```

What's missing: sort by, limit to 10 and get product.name along with quantity count

**Latest development:**

Items are selected but need to show product.name

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base 
def top_ten_products
  Item.find_by_sql(
    "SELECT i.product_id, sum(i.quantity) AS sum_quantity
    FROM   orders o
    JOIN   items i ON i.order_id = o.id 
    WHERE  o.client_id = 2 
    GROUP  BY 1
    ORDER  BY 2 DESC
    LIMIT  10;"
   )
 end
```

Console output

```
=> [#<Item product_id: 1>, #<Item product_id: 37>, #<Item product_id: 75>, #<Item product_id: 12>, #<Item product_id: 32>, #<Item product_id: 33>, #<Item product_id: 2>, #<Item product_id: 34>, #<Item product_id: 84>, #<Item product_id: 85>]
```

Client#show

```
<%= @client.top_ten_products %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `product_id` is a column of table `items`, the query could look like this in **PostgreSQL**:

```
SELECT i.product_id
      ,p.name
      ,sum(i.quantity) AS sum_quantity
FROM   orders o
JOIN   items i ON i.order_id = o.id 
LEFT   JOIN product p USING (product_id)
WHERE  o.client_id = 2 
GROUP  BY 1,2
ORDER  BY 3 DESC, 2 -- with same quantity, order by name
LIMIT  10;
```

#### Note:

I changed your quantity aggregation to a `sum` and added a commented column for `count`, as I suspect you mistakenly had a count where you want a sum.

#### Edit2:

`sum()` is confirmed.
Included name from table product per request.
`LEFT JOIN` is just a precaution for missing entries in table `product`, if referential integrity is guaranteed, it can be a plain `JOIN` instead.

Comment: Thanks. Almost there. I edited my question above with the latest development

Comment: Thanks for the update however there is no name column under item. The name column is part of the product table. Please advise.

Comment: @Gaelle: I edited in my guess. If that's not it, you need to provide the information how the table `product` is linked to table `item`.

Comment: This is where I'm not sure. For now I have `Item belongs_to :product` but nothing in the Product table as I'm not sure how it should be set. Please advise. Thx

Comment: @Gaelle: do you see a column `product_id` in both tables? IOW, does my latest version work? Just try `SELECT * FROM product LIMIT 10` and `SELECT * FROM item LIMIT 10` to see and figure out how they are tied together.

Comment: Your latest work `SQLException: cannot join using column product_id - column not present in both tables: SELECT i.product_id, p.name, sum(i.quantity) AS sum_quantity`. Product table: `["id", "active", "name", "price", "unit", "conditioning_id", "category_id", "supplier_id", "farm_id", "created_at", "updated_at", "image"]` while Items `["id", "order_id", "product_id", "quantity", "price", "color_id", "created_at", "updated_at"]`. Not sure about the relationship between Product and Item. I just want to reference selected product within the item table but not sure if there should be any?

Comment: @Gaelle: How could I possibly know? I am good with postgresql, with magic not so much. ;)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Managed to make it work. Marked as answered